# NodeJS Express req.params, enrouten controllers not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Folks,
  Trying to use https://github.com/krakenjs/express-enrouten for my Controllers.

For some reason, I am not able to get the behavior I want, and the `req.params` are not being set at all.

app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser());
var controllerPath = __dirname + '/controllers';
app.use(enrouten({directory: controllerPath }));
```

pingController.js:

```
module.exports = function registerRoutes(app){
    app.get('/', pong);
};

function pong(req, rsp) {

    console.log (req.params);

    rsp.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var response = {
        ping: 'pong',
        service: 'ShuttleService',
        env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
        params: req.params
    };
    rsp.send(response);
};
```

Problems:

1. `req.params` is `{}` instead of `{param:foo}` if i hit `http://localhost:3000/pingController?param=foo`
2. The route to the page is not `http://localhost:3000/` but the actual file name, ie `http://localhost:3000/pingController/`
3. If I replace the `app.get('/', pong);` with `app.get('/ping', pong);` the page is not found...  How do i get this controller to work for `/ping` uri instead of the filename in the uri?
4. `req.query` works...  why doesnt `req.params` get set?

How do I get enrouten to pass the `req.params`?  and also, how to get expected uri path behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here go the answers for each item:

1. `req.params` returns the route parameters, in the path of the URL. If you want to get the param `param` with `req.params`, you have to pass them in the path, so your code should look like:

   ```
   module.exports = function registerRoutes(app){
     app.get('/:param', pong);
   };
   ```

   and pass it in the URL like `http://localhost:3000/pingController/foo`. Now, if you call `req.params`, you're gonna have `{ param: foo }`;
2. This is how the `express-enrouten` module works (see the [docs](https://github.com/krakenjs/express-enrouten#directory)). Based on your code, you've defined that your controllers are going to be under the `controllers` directory. So, if you have a controller called `pingController`, the URL to call it is `http://localhost:3000/pingController/`;
3. If you change `/` to `/ping`, the URL to reach that is now `http://localhost:3000/pingController/ping`, and so on;
4. `req.query` returns the URL query parameters (after the `?`, see the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)). That's it returns your data when you call the URL `http://localhost:3000/pingController?param=foo`.

Comment: so with enrouten, can i have arbitrary controller files, and define routes inside them?

Comment: Yes, you can, like when you've done `/ping`, and called `http://localhost:3000/pingController/ping`. But remember the full URL is formed following the pattern `<main_URL>/<the_directory_structure>/<your_custom_route>`.

Comment: Yes you can. I thought that your goal was to have the controllers directory structure in the URL, since you were using the `directory` option. If you want to make `pingController` to be called by your `/` route, you have to use the `routes` option (see the [docs](https://github.com/krakenjs/express-enrouten#routes)). In your case you'd have to do this:
    app.use(enrouten({
      routes: [
        { path: '/', method: 'GET', handler: require('./controllers/pingController') }
      ]
    }));

Comment: thanks!  my goal is to have many controller files, and to define the routes either inside the controller files, or elsewhere.  Anyway i can define the routes inside the controller files themselves?  It looks like the `routes` option dictates me to define the routes in the main app.js file.

Comment: I haven't played too much with `express-enrouten`, but I don't see why it wouldn't work, since you export your express app variable in your main `app.js` file when you do `module.exports = app`. So every other file in your directory structure can see it.